# Writing function to Match words off by 1 character JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, function, match

I am attempting to write a JavaScript function, `OneLetterOff`, that will take in a String, and an Array of accepted words (`WordList`).

It should return an array of words from the `WordList` that only differ from the word given in the String by only one letter, at a single position.

For example:

```
WordList = ["marc", "bark", "parc", "shark", "mark"];
OneLetterOff("park", WordList); // should return ["bark", "parc", "mark"]
```

Words that pass the test have to be of the same length, and we can safely assume they are all lower case letters.

How do I use Regular Expressions to solve this algorithm? Essentially, are there ways other than having to use Regular Expressions to solve it?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for words in a list with a [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of 1 from a given word.

As found at [Algorithm Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#JavaScript), a JavaScript implementation of the algorithm is as follows:

```
function levenshteinDistance (s, t) {
        if (s.length === 0) return t.length;
        if (t.length === 0) return s.length;

        return Math.min(
                levenshteinDistance(s.substr(1), t) + 1,
                levenshteinDistance(t.substr(1), s) + 1,
                levenshteinDistance(s.substr(1), t.substr(1)) + (s[0] !== t[0] ? 1 : 0)
        );
};
```

Using that method with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (polyfill needed for IE<9) to include only items with a distance of 1, we get a very simple bit of code:

```
var oneLetterOff = function (word, list) {
   return list.filter(function (element) {
       return levenshteinDistance(word, element) === 1;
   });
};

oneLetterOff('park', ['marc', 'bark', 'parc', 'shark', 'mark']);
// returns ["bark", "parc", "mark"]
```

One great feature to this approach is that it works for any distance--just change what you're comparing to in the filter.

***If*** you really wanted to use regular expressions (which I would not recommend for this), you would need to:

1. Iterate the given word to create a set of strings representing regular expression subpatterns where each has one char optional
2. Combine those string subpatterns into a regular expression using `new RegExp()`
3. Iterate the list of words testing them against the expresison
4. When you get a match, add it to a set of matches
5. Return the set of matches

It wouldn't take long to write, but given the answer I gave above I think you'll agree it would be a silly approach.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not the best for it but to give you an idea:

```
"mark".match(/.ark|p.rk|pa.k|par./) //true
```

You can, of course, build regular expressions automatically and just "." might not be what you are looking for, depending on the possible characters you need to include.

I suggest you figure out the rest on your own as it looks a lot like homework ;-)

There are many non-regexp ways to solve it. For short words pre-compiled regexp will probably be the most efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution inspired by [JAAuide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239567/jaaulde) and using all the power of JavaScript functions

```
function lDist (s, t) { 
  /* If called with a numeric `this` value 
       returns true if Levenshtein distance between strings s and t <= this
     else
       returns the Levenshtein distance between strings s and t                         */
  return this.constructor === Number ? lDist.call (null, s, t) <= this :
     s.length && t.length 
       ? Math.min (lDist (s.slice (1), t) + 1,
                   lDist (t.slice (1), s) + 1,
                   lDist (s.slice (1), t.slice (1)) + (s.charAt (0) !== t.charAt (0)))
       : (s.length || t.length) };

['marc', 'bark', 'parc', 'shark', 'mark'].filter (lDist.bind (1, 'park'));
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/zzotfbqh/1/)